# Start setInterval loop from 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I have a slideshow in html, rotating client's ads every 10 seconds, however the first ad always display from 20 seconds. I figured that is because the setInterval starts at 10 seconds, therefore the select statement is only executed after 10 seconds and therefore the first ad's time is doubled.

I need the setInterval to start on 0 seconds.

Here is my setInterval:

```
<script>
setInterval(function() { 
$('#slideshow > div:first')
.fadeOut(0)
.next()
.fadeIn(0)
.end()
.appendTo('#slideshow');
},  10000);
</script>
```

Full code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-us" xml:lang="en-us">
<head>
<style>
body {
margin: 0;
}
</style>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script>
function handler() {
$('#slideshow > div:first')
.fadeOut(0)
.next()
.fadeIn(0)
.end()
.appendTo('#slideshow');
}
handler();
setInterval(handler, 10000);
</script>

</head>
<body>
<?PHP
echo "<div id='slideshow'>";
//Getting ads from the database
require_once('connect_pdo.php');
$sqlst = $conn->prepare("SELECT ads from adlist");
$sqlst->execute();
while($resultst = $sqlst -> fetch()){
$adlist = $resultst["Monday_Morning"];
echo "<div class='slideshow'>";
//Display ad as an image
//<object data='/$adlist'></object>
echo "<iframe id='frame' src='/$adlist' style='position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999; autoplay'>
Your browser doesnt support iframes
</iframe>";
echo "</div>";
}
echo "</div>";
?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do share parsed/browser rendered html than `php-wrapped` html as once could not execute that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define `callback` as a function and invoke it. Also pass it as first argument for `setInterval`

```js
function handler() {
  alert(); //Just for demo
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(0)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(0)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
}
handler();
setInterval(handler, 10000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @CharlesTester, Run this snippet..Don't you get `alert` ?

Comment: Yes thanks i did get the `alert`. That indicates there might be an issue with my `<div>`. I updated the question with my full code. Do you maybe see anything else wrong?

Comment: @CharlesTester, I'm glad it helped! _Happy Coding_

Answer (score 0):

Just call the callback once in front of your setting of the interval.

Setting `setInterval` waits for the given delay time before the first call of callback is made.

Comment: While your suggestion might be all that is needed to resolve the original question, some explanation on what caused the problem and how it is being solved with your suggestion might contribute to better insight with the OP and other readers of the answer later on.